# How to make markers unlickable when hidden by other objects

Tags: java, android, google-api, maps, google-maps-markers

I am creating a maps app for my school and I have pop ups and slide ups which cover parts of the screen but the markers behind these screens are not visible but can still be clicked through the object which makes for a very annoying experience. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue or if there was some way to check when a marker was behind another layout or pop up.

I have tried doing an if check which checks if the marker .isVisible() but it doesn't seem to read as not visible when hidden behind objects.